# Convert Between 3D Skeletal Systems DirectX

Tags: c++, matrix, 3d, directx, skeletal-animation

I'm trying to convert between two different skeletal formats.  I have a hierarchical skeleton.

Now in one format, a given node's matrix is calculated by (DirectX) (recurively, 
from bottom node to top, where matScale/matRotate/matTranslationFromParent are that particular nodes SRT):

`appliedMatrices = appliedMatrices * matScale * matRotate * matTranslationFromParent;`

But I need to convert it to a format that uses (recurively, from bottom node to top, where the translationIn is vector subtraction of (ParentPos - EndPartPos) and translation out is (EndPartPos - ParentPos), andmatScale/matRotate/matTranslationFromParent are that particular nodes SRT):

`appliedMatrices = appliedMatrices * matScale * matTranslationOut * matRotate * matTranslationIn * matTranslationFromParent;`

How do I convert from the first format to the second skeletal format (and back)?

Comment: Do you have control over the in- and out-translations? Are these inverse to each other (as the subtraction suggests)? Converting from format 1 to format 2 could be achieved by setting these translations to the identity, right?

Comment: They are inverses, but unfortunately, I don't have control over the skeleton.  So I can't just get rid of them (it would move the skeletal nodes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we compare the two versions, we see that the following two parts need to match:

```
matRotate1 * matTranslationFromParent1 
            = matTranslationOut * matRotate2 * matTranslationIn * matTranslationFromParent2
```

Since `matRotate1` and `matRotate2` are the only rotations, those two have to be equal. So this is simple:

```
matRotate1 = matRotate2
```

Then, for the two conversions, only one unknown is left:

```
//conversion 1 -> 2
matTranslationFromParent2 = (matTranslationOut * matRotate2 * matTranslationIn)^-1 * matRotate1 * matTranslationFromParent1
//conversion 2 -> 1
matTranslationFromParent1 = matRotate1^-1 * matTranslationOut * matRotate2 * matTranslationIn * matTranslationFromParent2
```

If performance is critical, you can do these calculations only on the translation vectors and not the entire matrices.